# Windows 7 Ctrl+Shift+Start/End/Page up/Page Down globally stops working after a while ... Putty?

Tags: windows, putty, shift, ctrl

I don't know how to narrow down this error. I need those key combinations.

On Windows 7 with some editors like Notepad++.

Only Chrome (+ Console), PSPad and Putty are in use.
This issue is new since a few weeks.
Is it possible that Putty is causing this?

Comment: Have you turned on CapsLock?

Comment: No Capslock. No Scroll Lock.